# how can I use two Jssor jquery image slider on the same page?

Tags: jquery

Good morning admins,  please. Am new here,  Am using jssor jquery image slider on my website.

But the main problem am having is, two jquery can't work on same page.

Only one will work out of the  two jquery.... The second one will not slide. Plz how can I get it fix..... ?

Comment: Okay. Example, after installing the jssor script.zip I
include('../demos-jquery/slider-with-
caption.source.html'); on the first page of my site, it
works, so I decide to include another jquery under
it. include('../examples-jquery/slider-with-
slideshow.source.html'); on that same page, but
only the first slider-with-caption own that is on top
of the 2nd one is working, the 2nd slider-with-
slideshow is not sliding.

Answer (score 0):

Different slider uses different name.
If you have 2, please name the first as 'slider1', and name the second as 'slider2'.

Please open ../examples-jquery/slider-with-slideshow.source.html and replace all 'slider1' with 'slider2'.

Comment: Okay. Example, after installing the jssor script.zip I include('../demos-jquery/slider-with-caption.source.html'); on the first page of my site, it works, so I decide to include another jquery under it. include('../examples-jquery/slider-with-slideshow.source.html'); on that same page, but only the first slider-with-caption own that is on top of the 2nd one is working, the 2nd slider-with-slideshow is not sliding.